# Vulnserver windows 10 only a few exploits

Tags: professional-education, exploit-development

I am playing around with vulnserver on my windows 10 (up to date) host. The weird thing is I only get crashes with KSTET and GTER and nothing with the other ones.

As I found this weird I cheated a bit and searched for other peoples solutions. But when I use those I still do not get a crash.

I googled, but I honestly do not know why this would be and how I would find out. Does anyone have the same experience, or a reason why this could be?

I used the precompile version 1.00 from the official github of vulnserver.

Comment: So I tried to work with a windows 7 VM. And here all the exploits are working. I'll report it to the creator of vulnserver as well

Comment: Anyone know how to contact that guy? :D